как сделать 3D разрез объекта в Unity
нужно сделать чтобы, объект разрезался вот так, а управлять этим можно было slider


гугли 3d slice unity

Если речь исключительно о визуале, то проще всего это сделать шейдером. Резать меш очень трудно и затратно.
